# Cannot load pages with wpbakery page builder error 404

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have two error's on my website.

1. When ever i visit my website as an admin following error is being displayed on the top "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/akwadsa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/redux-framework/ReduxCore/inc/fields/spacing/field_spacing.php on line 320"
2. When i try to open a page with WPbakery page editor finds the following error under inspect network

```
"frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.0.5:10 Uncaught TypeError: window.vc.frame_window.jQuery is not a function
    at window.vc.ShortcodesBuilder.buildFromContent (frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.0.5:10)
    at Object.vc.build (frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.0.5:10)
    at frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.0.5:10"  AND this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
```

Where as when i open the website as a visitor i can surf it smoothly.

I am a beginner to the web development kindly help with briefing thank you.

Comment: First try to change the theme and see if is there any error occur or not?

Comment: the theme was working fine before